# unable to Load data from CoLab to Bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load 5 SQL files to 5 different tables in bigquery to visualize the data in data studio.i have uploaded these files in CoLab's storage section and authorized the project.

```
datasets = [r"/file1.sql",r"/file2.sql",,r"/file3.sql",r"/file4.sql",,r"/file5.sql"]
f = open(datasets[1], "r")
data=f.read()
data = data.replace('\n','')
import pandas as pd

df = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq('''data''', project_id='newproject1', dialect='standard')

df.head()

df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable1','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable2','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable3','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable4','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable5','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')

)
```

I get below error when I run the query.

```
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in _download_results(self, query_job, max_results, progress_bar_type)
    549 
--> 550             query_job.result()
    551             # Get the table schema, so that we can list rows.
```

Also I want to know how to change python code to load the data to 5 respected tables.

Comment: Currently, currently loading ***sql files*** into BigQuery is not supported. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#overview) you can find all the supported formats. Also, as an alternative you could upload these files to Cloud SQL and query them using federated queries within the BigQuery console, such as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#overview). Would that attend your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a typo or if it is the issue but try replacing:

```
df.to_gbq(dataset1.testtable1','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq(dataset1.testtable2','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq(dataset1.testtable3','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq(dataset1.testtable4','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq(dataset1.testtable5','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
```

with

```
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable1','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable2','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable3','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable4','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
df.to_gbq('dataset1.testtable5','newproject1',chunksize=None,reauth=False,if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Sorry!!thats a typo..quotes have been included in the real query...i want to know if anything missing in the code..i am thinking if I upload the file to google drive and then include ``from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')`` in the code..let me know if its correct